# How to detect changes in google calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

When Google Calendar has been modified, do you receive any signal from the calendar?

if so, What is the method? please help me :)

```
 public IList<Event> CalendarLoad(string username="", string userid="", string userpassword="")
    {
        scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar);
        UserCredential credential;
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, scopes, username, CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore("Calendar.VB.Sample")).Result;
        }
```

Comment: Does your code return an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than polling Calendar regularly you can [use push notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push) to receive updates when Calendars change.